# The port 8888 is already in use

Tags: 18.04, jupyter

I tried opening my Jupyter notebook from the terminal, but it's showing:

```
503 Service Unavailable Failed to connect to server localhost.
```

And this shows on the terminal:

```
[I 18:55:37.270 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.271 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.271 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.271 NotebookApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.271 NotebookApp] The port 8892 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.271 NotebookApp] The port 8876 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:55:37.312 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/aman/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:55:37.312 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/aman/anaconda3/envs/py36/share/jupyter/lab
[I 18:55:37.315 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/aman
[I 18:55:37.315 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:55:37.315 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8960/?token=ee8fca59f9c0395f35bea80647fdd647370551e352fcfd60
[I 18:55:37.316 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:55:37.318 NotebookApp] 

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
http://localhost:8960/?token=ee8fca59f9c0395f35bea80647fdd647370551e352fcfd60
```

Results of `sudo netstat -ntlp` :

```
tcp 0 0    127.0.0.1:8897     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 5726/python 
tcp 0 0    127.0.0.1:8931     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 4077/python 
tcp 0 0    127.0.0.1:8932     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 8177/python 
tcp 0 0    127.0.0.1:8806     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 3446/python 
tcp 0 0    127.0.0.1:8809     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN 4800/python
```

Comment: Please, consider put text of logs instead image.

Comment: okay, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: could you put the output of the command: "sudo netstat -ntlp"?

Comment: it's showing command not found.

Comment: It is parts of net-tools, pleas install it. It will show you the port used in the system and from who

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8897          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5726/python         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8931          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4077/python         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8932          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8177/python         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8806          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3446/python         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8809          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4800/python